# A nice colored box with circle with some modifications

Tags: tikz-pgf, tcolorbox

I would like to make a particular box as in this image.

[image]

I have read the two guide `mdframed` and `tcolorbox` but I have not found anything that could be adapted to this image. I apologize at the beginning if I have not provided for any `MWE` but I do not know where to start. With sincerity I think you could do with `TikZ` I suppose.

Into my book I use `Times New Roman` as text, `Optima font` (`urw-classico`) for the header and the name of the image (for example Figure 1:)

Is it possible to use a different default font similar to the image to write Quick Test (or another text) with the side border made from dots or small triangles with a colored dot at the end?

Comment: The danger of asking such a wild mix of questions is that you may either get no answer or an answer by someone who knows everything a little bit. Experts on tcolorbox may know little about fonts, and vice versa. How about disentangling these two topics?

Comment: You are a high-rep user, you should set a good example and add a MWE. Sorry but -1

Answer (score 2):

This is the code David Purton's answer posted into chat. Thank you very much to you David.
For me no vote please, thank you very much.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage[breakable,skins]{tcolorbox}

\newtcolorbox[auto counter, number within=section]{quickquiz}[1][]{%
  enhanced, breakable, fonttitle=\sffamily\bfseries\Large,
  title=Q, fontupper=\bfseries, left=\tcboxedtitlewidth,
  boxsep=0pt, top=2mm, right=2mm, bottom=2mm+0.7\baselineskip,
  sharp corners, colback=white, colbacktitle=orange, frame hidden,
  pad before break=-0.7\baselineskip,
  before upper = {\begingroup\sffamily\bfseries\Large
    \textcolor{green!50!black}{uick Quiz}
    \textcolor{orange}{\thetcbcounter}\quad\endgroup},
  attach boxed title to top left={
    yshift=-\tcboxedtitleheight+2pt-2mm},
  boxed title style={
    empty, left=0mm, right=0mm, top=0mm, bottom=0mm, boxsep=2pt},
  underlay boxed title={
    \path[fill=tcbcolbacktitle] (title) circle (\tcboxedtitleheight/2);},
  overlay unbroken={
    \coordinate[xshift=\tcboxedtitlewidth/2,
      yshift=-\tcboxedtitleheight-0.7\baselineskip] (nw) at (frame.north west);
    \node (sw) [circle, fill=orange, inner sep=2pt,
      xshift=\tcboxedtitlewidth/2, yshift=\tcboxedtitlewidth/2]
      at (frame.south west) {};
    \draw[gray, line cap=round, line width=2pt,
      dash pattern=on 0pt off 4\pgflinewidth] (nw) -- (sw);},
  overlay first={
    \coordinate[xshift=\tcboxedtitlewidth/2,
      yshift=-\tcboxedtitleheight-0.7\baselineskip] (nw) at (frame.north west);
    \coordinate[xshift=\tcboxedtitlewidth/2,
      yshift=0.7\baselineskip] (sw) at (frame.south west);
    \draw[gray, line cap=round, line width=2pt,
      dash pattern=on 0pt off 4\pgflinewidth] (nw) -- (sw);},
  overlay middle={
    \coordinate[xshift=\tcboxedtitlewidth/2,
      yshift=-0.7\baselineskip] (nw) at (frame.north west);
    \coordinate[xshift=\tcboxedtitlewidth/2,
      yshift=0.7\baselineskip] (sw) at (frame.south west);
    \draw[gray, line cap=round, line width=2pt,
      dash pattern=on 0pt off 4\pgflinewidth] (nw) -- (sw);},
  overlay last={
    \coordinate[xshift=\tcboxedtitlewidth/2,
      yshift=-0.7\baselineskip] (nw) at (frame.north west);
    \node (sw) [circle, fill=orange, inner sep=2pt,
      xshift=\tcboxedtitlewidth/2, yshift=\tcboxedtitlewidth/2]
      at (frame.south west) {};
    \draw[gray, line cap=round, line width=2pt,
      dash pattern=on 0pt off 4\pgflinewidth] (nw) -- (sw);},
  #1}

\begin{document}
\section{First Section}

\begin{quickquiz}[label=QQ:A]
  \lipsum[1]
\end{quickquiz}

\begin{quickquiz}[label=QQ:B]
  \lipsum[2]
\end{quickquiz}

\section{Second Section}

\begin{quickquiz}[label=QQ:C]
  \lipsum
\end{quickquiz}

\begin{quickquiz}[label=QQ:D]
  \lipsum[4]
\end{quickquiz}

Cross references work: see Quick Quiz \ref{QQ:A}.

\end{document}
```

Comment: Nice trick dividing the title into a title and before upper parts.

Comment: @Ignasi This is not my answer :o) but of David Purton.

Comment: yes I know, but even in this case it's a nice trick  and I don't know how to congrat David Purton for it. ;-)

Comment: @Ignasi I also congratulated him in the chat room. And I also congratulated you on your pleasant comments. I can thank him if you want from you if you authorize me.